# Data Covering UITableView Cell

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I am developing one app ,here i need to display total letters in UITableViewCell,i have change the TableViewCell height, width but i can't fit total letters,

[image]

Above ScreenShot i need to display total letters in 3rd and 4th cell ,
can you please suggest me ,thanks@

Comment: Did you try setting the numberOfLines property to 0?

Comment: cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

Comment: have you used custom cell for Tableview?

Comment: ok now post your answer and close this question it help to other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all.I got the total letters in `UITableviewCell` as follows:

```
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
```

Using the above code will not decrease the font size. The letters will fit into the `UITableViewCell`

```
cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

Here font size will decrease and adjust to a single line in `TableViewCell`

[image]